# Exclude css isolation assets from dotnet publish

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, webpack, msbuild, dotnet-publish

I'm using RazorPages (on ASP.NET Core 6) and the css isolation feature. The css files are generated at `obj/{Debug,Release}/net6.0/scopedcss/Pages/`, and are included when performing a `dotnet publish`.

I also use Webpack, so I don't need to publish those css files (they are already bundled by Webpack).

I added variations of all of these to my `Project.csproj` without success:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Remove="obj/*/*/scopedcss/**/*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Remove="*.cshtml.rz.scp.css" />
</ItemGroup>
```

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <None Remove="obj/*/*/scopedcss/**/*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Remove="*.cshtml.rz.scp.css" />
</ItemGroup>
```

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PublishedFiles Remove="obj/*/*/scopedcss/**/*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);obj/*/*/scopedcss/**/*</DefaultItemExcludes>
</PropertyGroup>
```

How can I exclude the css isolation assets from the published output?

**UPDATE**
I found the msbuild stuff that controls this, but don't know how to prevent it from copying during publish. This [bit](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/32fed971590c96c929edbefdb78c66f02713de71/src/RazorSdk/Targets/Sdk.Razor.CurrentVersion.targets#L402) in the SDK imports the feature's msbuild targets, which are [here](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/32fed97159/src/RazorSdk/Targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.ScopedCss.5_0.targets) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/32fed97159/src/RazorSdk/Targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.ScopedCss.targets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [unsupported for now](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/41961#issuecomment-1143421967), but will be implemented in net7 (hopefully).

A workaround using "private" properties:

```xml
<Target Name="_RemoveScopedCssFiles" AfterTargets="_AddGeneratedScopedCssFiles">
  <ItemGroup>
    <StaticWebAsset Remove="@(StaticWebAsset)" Condition="$([System.String]::Copy('%(Identity)').EndsWith('rz.scp.css'))">
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

I'd be hesitant to use that as it's not part of the public contract / interface. It may suit you though.

A slow and ugly, but safe, workaround, is to let the runtime publish the files, then delete them:

```xml
<Target Name="DeleteScopedCssAssetsAfterPublish" AfterTargets="AfterPublish">
  <RemoveDir Directories="$(PublishUrl)/wwwroot/Pages" />
</Target>
```